# visual studio 2008 theme

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I just got into visual studio themes to color my ide. I found one I really like, but the problem is that it changed the size of the outlining  +/- that I use a lot. How do you increase the size of this?

Comment: I was just looking at my fonts and color settings, but I fail to see what you are referring to. What do you mean by "oulining +/-" ?

Comment: You know that plus/minus sign surrounded by a box that allows you to collapse regions of code. That box has become extremely tiny, i need it to be larger.

Comment: i.e. the little box on the margin that allows you to collapse regions in the source cod editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that box's size is set by the environment according to your font size. Actually it would be more precise to say it is set to the height of one line of code. I looked through the different items that can be personalized in the fonts and color window and did not see any that changed the size of that box.

Of course by changing my font size, the box scales with the height of the line it is on. Bigger font size = higher line = bigger box. The reverse is true.

Comment: The font that I was using has the plus and minus character be a lot smaller than the alpha characters